# how to fetch any attribute of any action class to a jsp page..?

Tags: jsp, struts2, action

I have two jsp pages. `one.jsp` and `two.jsp`. On `one.jsp` there is a form which have a submit button. User submits the form an action say `find.action` is executed and upon the success of which user navigates to `two.jsp`. `find.action` is mapped on struts.xml with defined success result. `find.action` is actioned with action class say `FindMyString`. In `FindMyString` there is an attribute say `String mystring = "Hello from Action class";` I want to display value of 'mystring' attribute on two.jsp.

Please suggest some way to do this by providing suitable coding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action needs a getter to expose any information that needs to be displayed in the JSP. So, start by creating a `getMyString()` method in your action. Then, you can output the value in JSP using either:

### OGNL

```
<s:property value="myString"/>
```

### JSTL

```
<c:out value="${action.myString}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OGNL to access field in action.

Here is a tutorial to get you started http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html

Here is the documentation for OGNL http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/ognl.html